# RegEx to extract data between an xml node in VBScript

Tags: regex, vbscript

First of all I have read all the references that match the above Title but none seem to answer my simple requirement. I must use a regex pattern as I need to feed it to a third-party library for processing.

Part 1:
The xml file to read from is a simple project.exe.config file. The regex that I have already used is

```
 <system.serviceModel>[\s\S]*?<\/system.serviceModel>
```

This reads the node and its contents however I ONLY need the CONTENTS to be returned.

Part 2:
This should be so simple that I am embarrassed to ask in such an esteemed forum as this. Can you recommend a program that will a) allow me to test various regex patterns on the subject file and b) be designed to tech me Regex patterns at the same time. I've paid for and installed RegExBuddy but the program itself seems to confusing for me, let alone the regex itself.

**Edit:**
VBscript does not support lookbehind.
I need to use VBscript as I'm using third-party tools.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That can be done quite simple using *positive lookbehind* (`?<=`) and *positive lookahead* (`?=`)

```
(?<=<system.serviceModel>)[\s\S]*?(?=<\/system.serviceModel>)
```

Example: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KeI8vo/1)

Positive lookbehind will look for match behind a specific pattern, in this case is `<system.serviceModel>` and vice versa, positive lookahead will look ahead `<\/system.serviceModel>` pattern.

To test and learn regex, [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is a good place that supports many language, has a friendly UI with explaination, and also have a nice debugger

**Edit**: OP edited the required to use the regex with VBScript, which doesn't support lookbehind. So the afternative is using capturing group:

```
<system.serviceModel>([\s\S]*?)(?=<\/system.serviceModel>)
```

It also work without the lookahead

```
<system.serviceModel>([\s\S]*?)<\/system.serviceModel>
```

I'm not familiar with VBScript, but the concept will be something like this:

```
Set regexObj = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
regexObj.Pattern = "<system.serviceModel>([\s\S]*?)(?=<\/system.serviceModel>)"
' or <system.serviceModel>([\s\S]*?)<\/system.serviceModel>
Set matchesObj= regexObj.Execute("<system.serviceModel>Something in side the xml tag!</system.serviceModel>")
If matchesObj.Count <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo(matchesObj(0).Submatches(0))
    ' or matchesObj.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0) 
    ' to access first submatch group ([\s\S]*?)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks but I should have mentioned that it needs to be OK to use with vbscript

Comment: @David I added a afternative, please take a look and see if it helps

Answer (score -1):

You can use lookarounds to only capture the content:

```
(?<=<system\.serviceModel>)[\s\S]*?(?=<\/system\.serviceModel>)
```

[Try it.](https://regex101.com/r/N80gI3/1)

Comment: Works of course but not in vbscript.

Comment: @David sure, but the question was edited to include VBScript afterwards ;)